# pandas: apply calculation for each month accross dataset with monthly specific constant

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am struggling to find a way to multiply monthly values from a df by a monthly index using python pandas.

I explain:
I have a traditional time serie dataset as such:

```
Id          AAA   BBBB  CCCC
2017-03-31       0       0       0
2017-04-30       0       0       0
2017-05-31       0       0       0
2017-06-30       0       0       0
2017-07-31       0       0       0
2017-08-31       0       0       0
2017-09-30       0       0       0
2017-10-31       0       0       0
2017-11-30       0       0       0
2017-12-31       0       0       0
2018-01-31       1       0       0
2018-02-28       0     204       0
2018-03-31       0       0       0
2018-04-30       0       0       0
2018-05-31      80     130       0
2018-06-30       0       0       0
2018-07-31       5     252       0
2018-08-31       0     290       0
2018-09-30       0       0       0
2018-10-31       1     230       0
2018-11-30      92      60       0
2018-12-31       0       0       0
2019-01-31       0      40       0
2019-02-28      16      48       0
2019-03-31       0       0       0
2019-04-30       0     224       0
2019-05-31      30     270       0
2019-06-30       0       0       0
2019-07-31      13     284       0
2019-08-31       0       0       0
2019-09-30       0     112       0
2019-10-31       0     134       0
2019-11-30       0       0       0
2019-12-31       0      50       0
2020-01-31       0       0       0
2020-02-29       0       0       0
2020-03-31       0       0       0
2020-04-30      10      67       0
2020-05-31       0       0       0
2020-06-30       0      54       1
```

and I have monthly indexes:

```
Id    AAA    BBBB       CCCC
1   0.055046  0.212131     0.0
2   0.880734  1.336427     0.0
3   0.000000  0.000000     0.0
4   0.412844  1.157441     0.0
5   4.541284  1.590984     0.0
6   0.000000  0.214783    12.0
7   0.990826  2.842559     0.0
8   0.000000  1.537952     0.0
9   0.000000  0.593968     0.0
10  0.055046  1.930394     0.0
11  5.064220  0.318197     0.0
12  0.000000  0.265164     0.0
```

the goal is to divide each month of first dataset by its corresponding index from the second dataset.
I.E the value for product AAA from the date 2019-06-30 should be divided by the seasonal index with index 6

how can this be done in pandas?

Comment: What to do with your CCCC monthly index? That is an obvious division by zero.

Comment: i am planning to user a filter to remove columns with 0 indexes, or adjust them to be over 0. my question is more about the method to achieve a calculation over many month with  monthly respective  constants

Comment: `df.set_index(df['Id'].dt.month).merge(df2.set_index('Id'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)` after this you can divide the columns of your choice

Comment: I tried your code and gives me the error: ```AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: `pd.merge()` with `left_on` being the month of the datetime index, `right_on` being the index (`Id`). The element-wise quotient can be computed subsequently.

### Data

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Id             AAA    BBBB    CCCC
2017-03-31       0       0       0
2017-04-30       0       0       0
2017-05-31       0       0       0
2017-06-30       0       0       0
2017-07-31       0       0       0
2017-08-31       0       0       0
2017-09-30       0       0       0
2017-10-31       0       0       0
2017-11-30       0       0       0
2017-12-31       0       0       0
2018-01-31       1       0       0
2018-02-28       0     204       0
2018-03-31       0       0       0
2018-04-30       0       0       0
2018-05-31      80     130       0
2018-06-30       0       0       0
2018-07-31       5     252       0
2018-08-31       0     290       0
2018-09-30       0       0       0
2018-10-31       1     230       0
2018-11-30      92      60       0
2018-12-31       0       0       0
2019-01-31       0      40       0
2019-02-28      16      48       0
2019-03-31       0       0       0
2019-04-30       0     224       0
2019-05-31      30     270       0
2019-06-30       0       0       0
2019-07-31      13     284       0
2019-08-31       0       0       0
2019-09-30       0     112       0
2019-10-31       0     134       0
2019-11-30       0       0       0
2019-12-31       0      50       0
2020-01-31       0       0       0
2020-02-29       0       0       0
2020-03-31       0       0       0
2020-04-30      10      67       0
2020-05-31       0       0       0
2020-06-30       0      54       1
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

df1["Id"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Id"])
df1.set_index("Id", inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Id       AAA      BBBB    CCCC
1   0.055046  0.212131     0.0
2   0.880734  1.336427     0.0
3   0.000000  0.000000     0.0
4   0.412844  1.157441     0.0
5   4.541284  1.590984     0.0
6   0.000000  0.214783    12.0
7   0.990826  2.842559     0.0
8   0.000000  1.537952     0.0
9   0.000000  0.593968     0.0
10  0.055046  1.930394     0.0
11  5.064220  0.318197     0.0
12  0.000000  0.265164     0.0
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

df2.set_index("Id", inplace=True)
```

### Code

```
df_joined = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on=df1.index.month, right_on="Id")

for col in df1.columns:  # or ["AAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"]
    df1[col] = (df_joined[f"{col}_x"] / df_joined[f"{col}_y"]).values

del df_joined
```

### Result

```
print(df1)

                  AAA        BBBB      CCCC
Id                                         
2017-03-31        NaN         NaN       NaN
2017-04-30   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2017-05-31   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2017-06-30        NaN    0.000000  0.000000
2017-07-31   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2017-08-31        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2017-09-30        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2017-10-31   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2017-11-30   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2017-12-31        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2018-01-31  18.166624    0.000000       NaN
2018-02-28   0.000000  152.645824       NaN
2018-03-31        NaN         NaN       NaN
2018-04-30   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2018-05-31  17.616163   81.710438       NaN
2018-06-30        NaN    0.000000  0.000000
2018-07-31   5.046295   88.652513       NaN
2018-08-31        NaN  188.562452       NaN
2018-09-30        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2018-10-31  18.166624  119.146661       NaN
2018-11-30  18.166667  188.562431       NaN
2018-12-31        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2019-01-31   0.000000  188.562728       NaN
2019-02-28  18.166666   35.916664       NaN
2019-03-31        NaN         NaN       NaN
2019-04-30   0.000000  193.530383       NaN
2019-05-31   6.606061  169.706295       NaN
2019-06-30        NaN    0.000000  0.000000
2019-07-31  13.120366   99.909975       NaN
2019-08-31        NaN    0.000000       NaN
2019-09-30        NaN  188.562347       NaN
2019-10-31   0.000000   69.415881       NaN
2019-11-30   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2019-12-31        NaN  188.562550       NaN
2020-01-31   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2020-02-29   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2020-03-31        NaN         NaN       NaN
2020-04-30  24.222224   57.886320       NaN
2020-05-31   0.000000    0.000000       NaN
2020-06-30        NaN  251.416546  0.083333
```